# type error : options.mongooseConnection.once is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
E:\Project\Unofficial_Project\web\node\node-cms\node_modules\connect-mongo\src\index.js:110
          options.mongooseConnection.once('open', () =>
                                     ^
TypeError: options.mongooseConnection.once is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection : mongoose.connection})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that where you defined your mongoose structure you are not exporting your db.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/codeial_development');
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "Error connecting to db"));

db.once('open', function(){
    console.log("connected to DB"); 
})

module.exports=db;
```

That last line is necessary. Now in the index.js(The root file).

```
const db = require("./config/mongoose");
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore(
        {
            mongooseConnection: db,
            autoRemove: 'disabled'
        }
)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

> module.exports =db

at the end of mongoose.js file in config folder